# How to set time between double tap on a single view item in Recycler view

Tags: android

I want to add like functionality in my app.. like- by double clicking on a single view item ( like- Instagram)

I want to set time between double tap done by user.

how can I do?

this is code in my onBindViewHolder() function:

```
            //on clicking each view item

            holder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    view_clicked++;

                    mLikeDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                            if(view_clicked==2){

                                if(dataSnapshot.child(post_key).hasChild(mcurrent_user_id)){

                                    mLikeDatabase.child(post_key).child(mcurrent_user_id).removeValue();
                                    view_clicked=0;
                                }
                                else {
                                    mLikeDatabase.child(post_key).child(mcurrent_user_id).setValue("Random value");
                                    view_clicked=0;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

and in my ViewHolder class code looks like:

```
     public void setLikeBtn(final String post_key) {

     mLikeDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
         @Override
         public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

             if(dataSnapshot.child(post_key).hasChild(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())){
                 like.setImageResource(R.drawable.like_red);
                 String likes= String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child(post_key).getChildrenCount());
                 like_count.setText(likes);
                 like_count.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             }

             else {
                 like.setImageResource(R.drawable.like_grey);
                 String likes= String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child(post_key).getChildrenCount());
                 like_count.setText(likes);
                 like_count.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             }
         }

         @Override
         public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

         }
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understands you correctly you want to set time between every two different double-taps. There are a couple of ways I can think of:

1. You can use *sleep* :

```
     try {
                Thread.sleep(interval);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

this will pause the main thread of the app and will give u the requested interval (notice interval is in milli sec i.e `interval = 1000` will give you 1 second.

2. You can use `CountDownTimer`:

```
    boolean canTapAgain = false;

     CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
             mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
         }

         public void onFinish() {
             canTapAgain = true;
         }
      }
```

start the timer after a double tap, and then the user can double tap again:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    view_clicked++;

    mLikeDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //notice the condition changed!
            if(view_clicked==2 && canTapAgain){
                if(dataSnapshot.child(post_key).hasChild(mcurrent_user_id)){
                    mLikeDatabase.child(post_key).child(mcurrent_user_id).removeValue();
                    view_clicked=0;
                }
            else {
                mLikeDatabase.child(post_key).child(mcurrent_user_id).setValue("Random value");
                view_clicked=0;
            }

            //and the below code added:
            canTapAgain = false;
            timer.start();
        }
    }   
});
```

Moreover I suggest you to read more about CountDownTimer [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html).